# Insert 'CR' prettier error using Atom Editor on Windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atom-editor, eslint, prettier

getting Insert 'CR' Prettier error for all lines.

I have .editorconfig

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf8
trim_trailing_whitespace  = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

is there any other config that needs to be updated ?